# How to tell Regex that any character before a certain string doesn't match?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to filter out links to videos from different video portals currently. The main problem I'm facing is that certain advertisement links got my video link in them, where regex tells me it "matches". I do not want that. Is there a way that I, for example, can say:

When there is anything before the http://, it won't match. How would it be for this example URL?

```
/http:\/\/example.com/
```

I tried something with ^[.] because I read the dot stands for any character, but it doesn't really work out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where the anchor `^` comes to work:

```
/^http:\/\/example.com/
```

The caret `^` matches the position before the first character in the string. In another word, it means `http` must be the start of the string.

Answer (score 2):

You could change what **does** matches so that it's only the beginning of the string. for example:

```
/^http[s]?:\/\/example.com
```

Would only match if the string begins with http://example.com or https://example.com. However, this won't work if you're trying to scan for a match in the middle of a block of text.